# Python pandas clarity on syntax for groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I run into this problem frequently and it isn't clear to me why the below python code will run

```
groups = session['time'].dt.total_seconds().groupby(session['user'])
```

but this python code will not run

```
groups = session['time'].dt.total_seconds().groupby(session[['user','date']])
or 
groups = session['time'].dt.total_seconds().groupby(session['user','date'])
```

Why can't I tack on another column to groupby in this way? How can I write this statement better?

Thank you for guidance, I'm a newbie with Python

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a series with `session['time']`, and thus a `SeriesGroupBy` object with this code, but you seem to want to access other columns in the dataframe.

The more common syntax is `grouped = df.groupby(columns_to_group_by)[columns_to_keep]`. I wouldn't name the variable `groups` because that is also the name of a property of the GroupBy object.

Comment: I see thank you, but if I say df.groupby(col group)[col keep].dt.total_seconds() I'm not longer able to do so